# Why dtypes are not changing when updating columns in Pandas 2.x but would change in Pandas 1.x?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

When changing the values and/or dtypes of specific columns there is a different behaviour from Pandas 1.x to 2.x.

For example, on column `e` in the example below:

- Pandas 1.x: Using `pd.to_datetime` to update the column will
  parse the date and change its dtype
- Pandas 2.x: Using
  `pd.to_datetime` to update the column will parse the date but
  will not change its dtype

What change from Pandas 1.x to 2.x explains this behavior?

**Example code**

```
import pandas as pd

# Creates example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['1', '2'],
    'b': ['1.0', '2.0'],
    'c': ['True', 'False'],
    'd': ['2024-03-07', '2024-03-06'],
    'e': ['07/03/2024', '06/03/2024'],
    'f': ['aa', 'bb'],
})

# Changes dtypes of existing columns
df.loc[:, 'a'] = df.a.astype('int')
df.loc[:, 'b'] = df.b.astype('float')
df.loc[:, 'c'] = df.c.astype('bool')

# Parses and changes dates dtypes
df.loc[:, 'd'] = pd.to_datetime(df.d)
df.loc[:, 'e'] = pd.to_datetime(df.e, format='%d/%m/%Y')

# Changes values of existing columns
df.loc[:, 'f'] = df.f + 'cc'

# Creates new column
df.loc[:, 'g'] = [1, 2]
```

**Results in Pandas 1.5.2**

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   a    b     c          d          e     f  g
0  1  1.0  True 2024-03-07 2024-03-07  aacc  1
1  2  2.0  True 2024-03-06 2024-03-06  bbcc  2

In [3]: df.dtypes
Out[3]: 
a             int64
b           float64
c              bool
d    datetime64[ns]
e    datetime64[ns]
f            object
g             int64
dtype: object
```

**Results in Pandas 2.1.4**

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   a    b     c                    d                    e     f  g
0  1  1.0  True  2024-03-07 00:00:00  2024-03-07 00:00:00  aacc  1
1  2  2.0  True  2024-03-06 00:00:00  2024-03-06 00:00:00  bbcc  2

In [3]: df.dtypes
Out[3]: 
a    object
b    object
c    object
d    object
e    object
f    object
g     int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [What’s new in 2.0.0 (April 3, 2023)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#what-s-new-in-2-0-0-april-3-2023):

> Changed behavior in setting values with `df.loc[:, foo] = bar` or `df.iloc[:, foo] = bar`, these now always attempt to set values inplace before falling back to casting (GH 45333).

So in Pandas 2+, whenever you set values with `.loc`, it will try to set them in place. If it succeeds, it will not create a new column, and will preserve the existing column's `dtype`.

Compare this with `df[foo] = bar`: this will create a new column with the `dtype` inferred from the values that are being set. The same happens when you do `df['d'] = pd.to_datetime(df.d)`, i.e., even in Pandas 2+, it will create a new column with `dtype` of `datetime64[ns]`.